# convert list<char> that represent binary string into ASCII C#

Tags: c#, list, char, ascii

I have a list of chars that represents a binary string.

```
List<char> myCharList = new List<char>();
```

For example, the charList holds the ascii H which represented by the binary sequence: 01001000

I try to convert this List into ASCII so I can show it in a Text Block.

Thanks

Comment: It seems fishy... Are you sure you don't want to convert the `List<char>` to a `string`?

Comment: Are you looking for `String MyString = new String(myCharList.ToArray());`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled hes `myCharList` contains a binary representation of the ASCII character and not the actual characters. I think he wants to get a `char` and not a `string`...

Comment: I think xanatos is right. Its fishy.

Comment: @AndreiV: AFAIK, a `char` is a `char`, no matter how you choose to represent it. If the list is of type `char`, it can be represented as a string the way I wrote in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another approach without linq

```
string binary = "01001000";
var list = new List<Byte>();
for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
{
    if (binary.Length >= i + 8)
    {
        String t = binary.Substring(i, 8);
        list.Add(Convert.ToByte(t, 2));
    }
}
string result = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(list.ToArray()); // H
```

Comment: linq is definitive not the right thing for this! you should do this in one line of code: int t = 0; for (int i = 0; i < chars.Count; i++) if (chars[i] == '1') t += (int)Math.Pow(2, i);

Comment: @FabianStern if you have multiple characters like `string binary = "0100100001001000"; //HH` your answer will mess up.

Comment: given was a list<char> with representation of 'H'. I thought that list<char> will be available for each single char representation. nevertheless I will rework my answer

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
string binary = "01001000";
string result =  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(binary.SplitByLength(8).Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x, 2)).ToArray());
```

**UPDATE**:
SplitByLength:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> SplitByLength(this string str, int maxLength)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < str.Length; index += maxLength)
    {
        yield return str.Substring(index, Math.Min(maxLength, str.Length - index));
    }
}
```

Comment: anyway `List<char> myCharList = new List<char>();` is not a binary string

Answer (score 1):

this should give you byte representation of an ASCII binary string:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<char> chars = new List<char> {'1', '0', '0', '0', '0','0','1'};
    chars.Reverse();
    int t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Count; i++)
    {
        if (chars[i] == '1') t += (int)Math.Pow(2, i);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} represents {1}",t,(char)t );
    Console.Read();
}
```

this should give you ASCII representations of bytes.
Remember that on each system the sizes of a char can differ, so
this code will use the systems default size for a char:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    List<char> chars = new List<char> {'A', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'};
    foreach (var c in chars)
    {
        string s = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(char) * 8); i++)
        {
            s = (1 & ((byte)c >> i)) + s;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} represents {1}",c,s );
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: here your solution as one-liner `char result = (char)binary.Reverse().Select((x, index) => x == '1' ? (int)Math.Pow(2, index) : 0).Sum();`